# Impersonating windows identity for Test Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, impersonation

I am using Windows Authentication of a specific account (not mine) to connect to database, for this, I've made changes in my web application's app domain's identity to that specific account and it works fine.

Database does not allow any other identity.

For the same web application I have a Visual Studio Test Project, the connection string in Test Project should also be authenticated for that specific account.
How can I do this?

I've tried impersonation but it did not work for test project

Comment: You might be able to set the [Thread.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx) to a [WindowsPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6547wf1(v=vs.110).aspx) so it connects as the other user. But are these unit tests you are running or integration tests? Unit tests generally shouldn't connect to a database anyway, and if you _are_ testing against a DB, you should do it against a dev instance which doesn't have such tight restrictions on who can connect.

Comment: they are both unit and integration tests, I understand Dev should not have these restrictions, but the leads are not agree, they want to use the same environment as production.]

Comment: did  you get any solution ?

Comment: no, i didn't find any.